# PHP com class isn't working

Tags: php, com

I am trying to use **PHP COM** class to access **Powerpoint application** installed in my windows server. The code -

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","On");

$excel = new COM("Excel.application",,) or die ("ERROR: Unable to 
instantaniate   COM!\r\n");

print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
```

It gives me "HTTP ERROR 500". I have checked that the "php_com_dotnet.dll" extension is loading as well. I have no idea why this error keeps showing up, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit - This has been fixed. But now this error has popped up - Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object `Powerpoint.application': Access is denied. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php(5): com->com('Powerpoint.appl...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

There is a `FATAL` error in your code. In your instantiation, parameters are wrongly provided as `,,`. Change it to below code:

```
$excel = new COM("Excel.application") or die ("ERROR: Unable to instantaniate COM!\r\n");
```

Comment: Ok that fixed ""HTTP ERROR 500" but now this error has popped up -

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object `Powerpoint.application': Access is denied. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php(5): com->com('Powerpoint.appl...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php on line 5

Comment: Its a permission issue. Check permissions.

Comment: Yes Samir i fixed the permissions .. now it is giving the server execution error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object `powerpoint.application': Server execution failed in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php(6): com->com('powerpoint.appl...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dashboard\testext.php on line 6

Comment: You need to read `COM` document once again to understand how to use it.